# How to use NPM modules in file run with CasperJS?

Tags: node.js, module, casperjs, cheerio

I know that CasperJS isn't usable with node directly, but can I not even use a service like `cheerio`, a node web scraping tool?

I tried `require('cheerio');` and it said not found.  So, I did:

**proxies/cheerios.js**

```
module.exports = require('cheerio');
```

**tests/file.js**

```
var cheerio = require('../proxies/cheerio.js');
```

Now, I get:

> Error: Cannot find module 'util'
>
> phantomjs://bootstrap.js:289
>
> phantomjs://bootstrap.js:254 in require

Any suggestions?  I really need to use this plugin in CasperJS, and SpookyJS isn't working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's running on top PhantomJS so if you want to include external libraries you need to [inject](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/inject-js.html) them into your code.

Comment: This wasn't what I was going for, but c'est la vie...  You can inject jQuery and use that rather than cheerio... Thanks.